# How to change position of element div?

Tags: html, css

Here is the picture of the website and how it looks:

[image]

And I want to make it so that there are two pictures first then below those two pictures put 3 pictures, but I don't know how to move them.

This is the code that I had tried:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Amey" height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/staff%201%20circle.png" width="756" /><br />
<h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;">Sandra Najera | MBA Management</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span class="Title">CARES Engagement Manager</span></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Ana V." height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/blanca.png" width="756" /><br />
<h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;"> | MBA Finance</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span class="Title">CARES Engagement Graduate Assistant</span></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Andres" height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/Joshua.png" width="756" />
<h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;"> | Ed.D. Educational Leadership and Administration</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span class="Title">CARES Engagement Manager</span></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Angie " height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/Sandra.png" width="756" />
<h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;"> | MA Latin American and Border Studies</h3>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span class="Title">CARES Engagement Community Worke</span></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Angie " height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/catherine.png" width="756" />
<h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;"> | CARES Undergraduate Assistant</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And I want to make it so that there are two pictures first then below those two pictures put 3 pictures, but I don't know how to move them. This is the code I want to make it look kind of like a pyramid but I don't know how!

Comment: please bother making a code pen as there is no css in the code provided

Comment: Please edit you question and remove all the mess!

Comment: please check the preview of your question, a lot of mess is going on here. The link is not supposed to be inside the code fences and also a lot of unneccesary things like *enter code here*, *Run code snippetHide resultsExpand snippet* .  Code indents are messed up so consider formatting the codes properly to make it better to read

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code you want!

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Amey" height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/staff%201%20circle.png" width="756" /><br />
      <h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;">Sandra Najera | MBA Management</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span class="Title">CARES Engagement Manager</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Ana V." height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/blanca.png" width="756" /><br />
      <h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;">Blanca A. Hernandez | MBA Finance</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span class="Title">CARES Engagement Graduate Assistant</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Andres" height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/Joshua.png" width="756" />
      <h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;">Dr. Joshua Acevedo | Ed.D. Educational Leadership and Administration</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span class="Title">CARES Engagement Manager</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Angie " height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/Sandra.png" width="756" />
      <h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;">Sandra I. Morales | MA Latin American and Border Studies</h3>
      <p style="text-align: center;"><span class="Title">CARES Engagement Community Worke</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-5"><img alt="Angie " height="756" src="/render/file.act?path=/cares-intern/_Files/images/catherine.png" width="756" />
      <h3 class="name" style="text-align: center;">Catherine Ross | CARES Undergraduate Assistant</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Check it [here](https://www.codeply.com/p/HFhWerOCB7#).